# AWS CLI command not found on MAC

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terminal

```html
pyop:~ MAC$ aws
-bash: aws: command not found
pyop:~ MAC$ which python
/usr/bin/python
pyop:~ MAC$ ls -al /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66576 Apr 28  2017 /usr/bin/python
pyop:~ MAC$
```

The screen capture at the end of this post has everything that is going wrong. I have an old install of Python 2.7 and a new one of Python 3.6. The AWS instructions have pip3 in them, long story short, the aws command is not working and I've followed the instructions from the [amazon site on how to get it to work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path) many, many times. I have messed around a lot with the .bash_profile with no success trying to follow solutions I've found on stackoverflow.

Thanks for the help. Please let me know if I need to supplement this post with more things. This is my first stack overflow post.

[screencapture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnwsD.jpg)

Comment: I have tried removing and adding the export path things in terminal to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path to the aws program?

Comment: @ColeTierney The objective is to install the aws command line interface as described here: [link] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html)

Comment: @ColeTierney There is no program, but I am trying to deploy the application I have coded for on the LightSail cloud platform. To do this, I need to use aws for aws.amazon.com like git for github.com. The aws command line interface will allow me to create instances of web applications and do other things, which I haven't learned yet.

Comment: I'm thinking we could break down the problem by starting with "does the program exist locally?" then "does it work?". Then maybe explore $PATH issues.

Comment: @ColeTierney The instructions for installation say: Adding the AWS CLI Executable to your Command Line Path
After installing with pip, you may need to add the aws executable to your OS's PATH environment variable. The location of the executable depends on where Python is installed.
pip installs executables to the same folder that contains the Python executable. Add this folder to your PATH variable.

Comment: @ColeTierney I don't know what the program is called if there is one. But whatever aws is supposed to use is in the usr/bin/python. I don't know if pip3 and aws point to the same location (I suspect they need to)

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, the program name is `aws`.  Try `find ~ -name aws` and `find /usr -name aws`, and finally `find / -name aws` if neither of the first two find anything.  Disregard any permission-related errors from these commands, as they may try to look into areas where they lack permission to look.  That's normal and harmless.  These will take some time.

Comment: thanks @Michael and atColeTierney, i didn't know aws was a program. This CLI stuff is still pretty new to me.  Here is what my terminal looks like now (pyop is my username):  pyop:~ MAC$ find ~ -name aws   
/Users/MAC/Library/Python/2.7/bin/aws   
/Users/MAC/Library/Python/3.6/bin/aws   
pyop:~ MAC$

Comment: So, it should be that either `/Users/MAC/Library/Python/2.7/bin` or `/Users/MAC/Library/Python/3.6/bin` is what you'd need to add to your `PATH` in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: After trying to add the new aws alias (which is most likely not what I'm supposed to do) the terminal gives me this: [screencapture](https://imgur.com/a/KL9Hz)

Comment: Oh, to path not alias, give me a sec...

Comment: I get the same error, but changed the export PATH thing here: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/pjwnv)

Comment: Uninstall aws cli and then again install it using sudo pip install awscli command.

Comment: Thanks ishan but I eventually fixed it by putting quotes in the right places in my .bash_profile